# iTunes app on iOS review from application

Tags: ios, objective-c, itunes

Application development is completed. It is not yet submitted on iTunes, but I have a flow to show the iTunes review screen from application.

How do we redirect the iTunes review from application?

I have tested using the below code...

```
NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=337064413";

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
```

Do we only need to change the application id for my application?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 7 use this link:

```
itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id337064413
```

Change `337064413` to your app's id

The code will look like this:

```
NSString *str = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id337064413";    
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
```

However, this approach will not bring you to the Review page, you'll get App Description page. There is no way to send user directly to Review page anymore.

Comment: As an aside: be careful [what you copy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220158/this-user-is-edit-spamming-dozens-of-answers-with-their-affiliate-code-can-they)... ;-)